# Java - Runtime.exec does not handle /bin/echo correctly (Debian)

Tags: java, linux, debian, pipe

I'm using this in my shell to start playing a song in
VLC by using remote control. I've written a TeamSpeak
Bot, which allows to use this by using Runtime.exec().

```
/bin/echo -n "add somemedia" | nc -U /tmp/vlc.sock
```

The problem is, instead of piping the string to the socket
it prints this:

```
"add somemedia" | nc -U /tmp/vlc.sock
```

This only happens when I do it in my Java application.

I'm using a debian linux if that helps.

Comment: Post your Java code.

Comment: Runtime.exec is for running processes, not for arbitrary shell commands.